# Scala + / - sign preceding of type params

Tags: scala

Hi I am trying to get my head around on Scala.

I was referring to API and found unfamiliar syntax

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.actors.CanReply

```
trait CanReply[-T, +R] extends AnyRef

abstract type Future[+P] <: () ⇒ P
```

What does this + and - preceding T and R meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean covariance and contravariance, see http://debasishg.blogspot.ch/2006/04/generics-in-scala-part-1_12.html

Specifically, quote:

> The + in type argument for the class definition indicates that
>   subtyping is covariant on that type parameter. A - in the same place
>   changes the relationship to contravariance. The default (without any
>   prefix) declaration indicates invariance of subtyping.

Comment: Woops, yeah, fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

A short (and not complete) answer without going into the details:

They specify the relationship between the type parameters and the inheritance relationship.

- `+` indicates that if `T` is a subclass of `S` then `Class[T]` is a subclass of `Class[S]`
- `-` indicates that if `S` is a subclass of `T` then `Class[T]` is a subclass of `Class[S]`
- If neither is present, than there will be no inheritance relationship between `Class t` and `Class s`

If you are familiar with Java, then you know that the third case is with every Java class with type parameters. (There is no relationship between `List<T>` and `List<S>`, even if `T` is the subclass of `S`)

Comment: would you be able to explain covariant , contravariant and invariant relate to your answer ?

Comment: `+` marks covariant, `-` marks contravariant, and the lack of `-` or `+` marks invariant type parameter

Answer (score 2):

I agree with answers here and just want to show some examples. With `[-T, +R]` co- and counter-variance you can do the following:

```
class A
class B extends A
class C extends B

trait CanReply[-T, +R] {
  def foo(r: T): R
}

class CR1 extends CanReply[B, B] {
  def foo(r: B): B = {
    println("arg of type [" + r.getClass() + "] for B in CR1")
    new B
  }
}

class CR2 extends CanReply[A, C] {
  def foo(r: A): C = {
    println("arg of type [" + r.getClass() + "] for A in CR2")
    new C
  }
}

class CR3 extends CanReply[C, A] {
  def foo(r: C): A = {
    println("arg of type [" + r.getClass() + "] for C in CR3")
    new A
  }
}

object Program {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    test(new CR1)
    test(new CR2)
    test(new CR3)
  }

  def test(cr: CanReply[C, A]): Unit = {
    val res: A = cr.foo(new C)
    println("result of type [" + res.getClass() + "]")
    println()
  }
}
```

will produce:

```
arg of type [class C] for B in CR1
result of type [class B]

arg of type [class C] for A in CR2
result of type [class C]

arg of type [class C] for C in CR3
result of type [class A]
```

So for counter-variance you can place any base class object where derived is expected and vise versa for co-variance you can place any derived class object where base is expected. Usually methods parameters are counter-variant and their return types are co-variant.

Comment: would you be able to add the output of this program to make it more usable?

Comment: Added. See "will produce".